# Store Arraylist in SharedPreferences with Gson

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am new in Java and Android development. I have a database that includes gender, phone number, name and hobby array. I want to store in my activity with SharedPreferences but I don't know how to apply Gson class. This is my code:

```
public class SessionManager {

SharedPreferences usersSession;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
Context context;

public static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";

public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_BIRTHDATE = "birthdate";
public static final String KEY_GENDER = "gender";
public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
public static final ArrayList<String> KEY_HOBBIES = new ArrayList<>();

public SessionManager(Context _context) {
    context = _context;
    usersSession = _context.getSharedPreferences("userLoginSession", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = usersSession.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(KEY_HOBBIES);
}

public void createLoginSession(String name, String birthdate, String gender, String phone, ArrayList<String> hobbies) {

    editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(KEY_HOBBIES);

    editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);
    editor.putString(KEY_BIRTHDATE, birthdate);
    editor.putString(KEY_GENDER, gender);
    editor.putString(KEY_PHONE, phone);
    editor.putString(KEY_HOBBIES, json);

    editor.commit();

}
```

I made 2-3 mistakes in this code, how can I store this Arraylist with other string values. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

to store ArrayList

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < hobbies.size; i++) {
            sb.append(hobbies.get(i)).append(",");
        }
        editor.putString(KEY_HOBBIES, sb.toString());
```

to retrieve it

```
    String[] array = playlist.split(",");

    hobbies = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **TYPE** to read data from sharedPreferences

**Read data**

```
           Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = sharedPreferences.getString("Set", "");
               Type type = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {
            }.getType();
            List<String> arrPackageData = gson.fromJson(json, type);
            for(String data:arrPackageData) {
               result.setText(data);
            }
```

and **save data**

```
        final ArrayList<String> arrPackage;
        String nameS = name.getText().toString().trim();
        String birhtdayS = birthday.getText().toString().trim();
        String gendarS = gendar.getText().toString().trim();
        String phoneS = phone.getText().toString().trim();
        arrPackage.add(nameS);
        arrPackage.add(birhtdayS);
        arrPackage.add(gendarS);
        arrPackage.add(phoneS);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(arrPackage);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("Set",json );
        editor.commit();
     }
```

Comment: Thank you but I want to store my hobby array with gson. I stored other string values already but I couldn't store hobby array.